# ExcludeFromBuild failing in VS2010 web deployment project

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment-project

I have a web deployment project that is misbehaving. I have inherited an App_Data folder that contains a substantial number of *.pdf* files. Some of the filenames include invalid characters and are overly long. In my deployment project file I include the following *ItemGroup* at the end:

```
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\*.pdf" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But when I build the project I keep getting the following error:

```
error : Copying file $([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(_WDPSourceWebPhysicalPath),
  App_Data\CWM2\393S097 Connection of an Embedded Network to elided's Network v1.pdf))
  to obj\Debug\Source\App_Data\CWM2\393S097 Connection of an Embedded Network to
  elided's Network v1.pdf failed. The path is not of a legal form.
```

I've tried adding wildcards to the App_Data folder but it's just not working. I guess it's conceivable that msbuild is unable to match those files for exclusion *because* the filename is invalid. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a similar bug with my deployment project.  I believe that VS2010 Web Deployment Projects has a bug that prevents copying any file that contains a quote character.

I filed a connect bug here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/631995/

The only workaround I know is to remove the quote character from the name of the file.

Comment: Thanks Wesley - I ended up using a PowerShell script to deal with the bad filenames.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround! you can change the file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets" by replacing the non working part with the one from the 2008 version.  To do that, search for

```
<Target Name="_CopyBeforeBuild"
```

and replace the content in the xml tag with the following (taken from webdeploymentproject 2008)

```
<Target Name="_CopyBeforeBuild" Condition=" '$(EnableCopyBeforeBuild)' == 'true' or '@(ExcludeFromBuild)' != ''  ">
    <CreateItem Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\*.*" Exclude="@(ExcludeFromBuild)">
        <Output ItemName="_WebFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>

    <RemoveDir Directories="$(CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath)"/>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath)"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_WebFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath)\%(_WebFiles.SubFolder)%(_WebFiles.RecursiveDir)" />

    <CreateProperty Value="$(CopyBeforeBuildTargetPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="_AspNetCompilerSourceWebPath" />
    </CreateProperty>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update - that's not something I had considered but looks promising. I guess you would need to be careful to reapply the change in the event that a service pack overwrote the file - unless the service pack fixed the problem :-)